# PDF: multiple columns to one column

Tags: pdf

I couldnt find any software that converts multiple columns to one column correctly.
Output folder type isnt important, But column must be on correct range.
Is there any software to do that?

Comment: I'm afraid that in order to get answers to this question, you'll need to expand upon "output folder type" and "on correct range".

Comment: all of converters I found shows columns like they are in the sma line. I mean : 2. line of  page contains both first column and second column's 2. lines. So in converted document's 2. line I have both two columns 2. line.

Comment: And another problem is converters doesnt protect layout; breaks most paragraph indentation when converting to txt files

Comment: What software have you tried? Have you tried using Adobe Acrobat Pro and exporting to RTF or HTML for example? It still isn't very clear what you are trying to accomplish by the way; and your question doesn't say what technology you want to use to do this conversion. This is about development right? You are trying to do this in code?

Comment: In addition to all the other comments: Please be aware that PDFs containing multicolumnar text don't necessarily are marked accordingly. Thus, that the *2. line of page contains both first column and second column's 2. lines* can be due to the fact that that is exactly how the text is presented in the PDF, the gap between the columns merely being a wider space.

Comment: so maybe a converter: that will read 2.line, then when it founds more than 10 space for example, it will take the end of line as second column's 2.line. ...etc

Answer (score 13):

Which system are you on? Windows, Mac or Linux?

1. There is a multi platform tool [k2pdfopt](http://willus.com/k2pdfopt/) which has a conversion preset for converting 2 columns to 1 column layout and comes with a GUI on Windows
2. On Windows you can do the conversion with a recent version of MS-Word >= 2013.

   - Open the file with MS Word   File -> Open
   - Confirm conversion
   - Select document or paragraph
   - Change Columns Layout -> Columns -> 1 Colum